# Ate vs Eaten: what is the difference?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I am learning English, and I have a question.

What is the difference between the two words Ate and Eaten? Why would I use one over the other? Or are they the same?

Comment: [List of common irregular verbs](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/irregular-verbs) (British Council) [Sentences with **ate**](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/ate) and with [**eaten**](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/eaten)

Comment: Some [uneducated, *very* relaxed, or facetious] native speakers say things like *The mice have ate (pronounced **ET**) the cheese.* But even most of *those* people know perfectly well it should be *have **eaten***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ate" is the past tense.  It is used to talk about events that occurred at a particular time in the past

> The horse ate an apple yesterday.

Using "eaten" would be a mistake:

> *The horse eaten an apple yesterday  (grammar error, no meaning)

"Eaten" is a participle.  It has many different uses.  It is used for the passive voice (with a auxiliary verb be/is/was )

> Apples are eaten by horses.

With "have/has", it is used to form the perfect aspect, for events occurring at an unspecified time in the past (but with a connection to the present)

> The horses have eaten apples since they were born.

And it is used to form a variety of phrases that modify or complete other structures:

> A half-eaten apple was on the table.

> Apples eaten by the horses are kept in that box.

The two forms are completely different, you must use the "right" one according to the grammar.  If you replace swap "ate" and "eaten" you get a grammar mistake.

Comment: thank you very much. I was showing a friend who's learning English how this site works and suggested using it for help, and so glad that you gave such a great and friendly answer. That's so great to see, as I was crossing my fingers I didn't just get some downvotes and one-line comments (which I personally don't mind but I find discouraging to new users of the site). So I really appreciate that -- thank you!!